# FsUnit Assert Sequence Containing Float Value

Tags: fsunit

I wanted to assert a sequence using equalSec and equalWithin for a sequence containing float values. I tried

```
seq { System.DateTime(2023, 1, 1), 1.581 }
|> should equalSeq (seq { System.DateTime(2023, 1, 1), ((equalWithin 0.01) 1.58) })
```

but I can't get it to work.

Any pointers?

Thank you in advance.